# Glassfish dont see my rest application

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, glassfish-4, glassfish-4.1

I have RestApplication class:

```
@ApplicationPath("/orcr")
public class RestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("jersey.config.server.disableMoxyJson", true);
        properties.put("jersey.config.disableMoxyJson", true);

        return properties;
    }
```

And some resource:

```
@Slf4j
@Stateless
@Path("/unhold")
public class UnholdResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/test")
    public Response test() {
        return Response.ok("cool").build();
    }
}
```

i deploy it on my local glassfish4.
Some logs:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer > Registering the Jersey servlet application, named lv.lpb.rest.RestApplication, at the servlet mapping /orcr/ *, with the Application class of the same name.
javax.enterprise.web > Loading application [orcr-unholder] at [/orcr-unholder-r75.6944126]
javax.enterprise.system.core > orcr-unholder was successfully deployed in 4,222 milliseconds.
```

But if i try ant of urls like:

localhost:8081/orcr-unholder/orcr/unhold/test

localhost:8081/orcr-unholder/orcr/unhold

localhost:8081/orcr-unholder/orcr

localhost:8081/orcr/unhold/test

localhost:8081/orcr/unhold

it`s always 404 Not Found

localhost:8081 - server is running

So, what can it be?

---

Solved

right url was: localhost:8081/orcr-unholder-r75.6944126/orcr/unhold/test

Comment: Ain't it necessary to register all your resource classes in your sub-application classes overriding getClasses() method ? try adding `public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return new HashSet<Class<?>>(Arrays.asList(UnholdResource .class));
    }`      in your `RestApplication ` class

Comment: The log message says the application is deployed in context "/orcr-unholder-r75.6944126".

Comment: @unwichtich thanks! that helps

Comment: @unwichtich how can i not mention project name and version in url, btw?

Comment: I guess this depends on your IDE and how it deploys the application on Glassfish. Normally the project name is used as URL context root if not configured otherwise.

Comment: @unwichtich i use netbeans as IDE. Gradle task to deploy my .war How can i config path to not use app context in URL?